# Flex 4, SWFLoader border resize issue

Tags: apache-flex, resize, swfloader

Following is the issue i am facing.

I have a MainPage, on initialize I am calling a method which would create a SWFLoader object (aka LoginPage) and loads it in the MainPage. When we run the MainPage in 800x500 window, the  LoginPage loads in that window size, however when we maximize the window the content of the LoginPage gets resized to 1027X660, but the border remains 800x500, and the remainig area of the window stays blank.

If we load the MainPage in maximized state everything works fine even we resize. the problem only happens when we first start the application in smaller size that maximized.

Answer (score 0):

there are such params as minWidhth and maxWidth and the same about Height, research in this way.

Anyway show your code, of loader and of login screen, so we could advice.